# Android background service with background thread causing anr error

Tags: android

I have implemented an android service which performs following long operations

1. when screen goes off start recording accelerometer data.
2. When data reaches 3000 samples I write it to the file.
3. then I perform data processing on the after reading recorded data.
4. Then I extract gait template from that data.
5. Then I compute similarity score.
6. I want to keep that service running as long as user explicitly does not quit this service.

In case if screen goes on I stop data recording and check if number of samples are more than minimum number of samples i repeat steps 2-5. else just drop recorded samples.

I have a broadcast receiver to get SCREEN_ON and SCREEN _OFF broadcasts writing file works fine but time taking part is feature (or template generation) I read from android documentation

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

Therefore I am trying to implement service with background thread. But still i am getting anr errors any help ?.

```
public class GaitAuthenticationService extends Service {

int mStartMode;       // indicates how to behave if the service is killed
IBinder mBinder;      // interface for clients that bind
boolean mAllowRebind; // indicates whether onRebind should be used
private int serviceState = 0; // This will maintain state of our service
private BroadcastReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = new ScreenOffBroadCastReciever();;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private PowerManager mPowerManager;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mLock;
private AccelRecorderTesting mAccelRecorder;
private Context context;
private boolean screenOff;
private KeyguardManager keyGaurdManager;
private boolean screenState;
private IntentFilter mfilter;

private Looper mServiceLooper;
  private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;


  // Handler that receives messages from the thread
  private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
      public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
          super(looper);
      }


      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
          // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.



          // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
          // the service in the middle of handling another job

          if (screenState==true && (keyGaurdManager.isKeyguardLocked() || keyGaurdManager.isKeyguardSecure())){
              Log.d("SCREEN ON OFF RECIEVER","screen is oFF(onStartCommand)");
              Log.d("GaitAuthenticationService", "Started recording data");
              // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
              // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
              mAccelRecorder.onStartButtonIsClicked();    

          }



         // stopSelf(msg.arg1);
      }
  }


@Override
public void onCreate() {

    mAccelRecorder = new AccelRecorderTesting();
    keyGaurdManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    mAccelRecorder = new AccelRecorderTesting(this.getApplicationContext());
    Log.i("GaitAuthenticationService", " is started");

    mfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    mfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, mfilter);

     // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",new Process().THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {




    // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
//  if(intent!=null){
        //screenOnOffReceiver = new ScreenOffBroadCastReciever();

         screenState   = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state",screenOff);
        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        if (screenState){
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

         if(screenState == false){
              Log.d("SCREEN ON OFF RECIEVER","screenON(onStartCommand)");
              try {
                  mAccelRecorder.onStopButtonIsClicked(true);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              Log.d("GaitAuthenticationService", "Stop Recording data");
          }


//  }

    return GaitAuthenticationService.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(" GaitAuthenticationService", "Service is destroyed");
    if(screenOnOffReceiver!=null){
        Log.i("screenreciever", "true");
        unregisterReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver);
        screenOnOffReceiver=null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Service#onUnbind(android.content.Intaent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    if(screenOnOffReceiver!=null){
        Log.i("screenreciever", "true");
        unregisterReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver);
        screenOnOffReceiver = null;
    }

    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

}

Here is my broadcast Reciever

```
public class ScreenOffBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private boolean screenOff;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent!=null){
        if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))) {


                screenOff = true;

        }
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
            screenOff = false;
        }

    Intent i = new Intent(context, GaitAuthenticationService.class);
    i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
    context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

}

Receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="ScreenOffBroadCastReciever" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What's your error?  Post the stack trace

Comment: When service is running, after running through all the steps mentioned in question i was getting something Fatal Signal exiting, and then it was saying something like printed traces.txt at /data/anr/traces.txt, and also when service was running then i wasnt able to click anywhere on the  screen, because my service was running in main UI thread. Then i added  android:process=":background" in manifest file and now my UI is no more blocked, and service is continuously running abst fine. code is fine didn't changed anything in my code.